# Mod_security rules-updater.pl fails to pull new release

Tags: apache, mod-security, updates

Mod_security has a rules updater distributed with their release packages on sourceforge:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-security/files/modsecurity-crs/0-CURRENT/

Usually, you can run the script and modsec will update the rules for you. However, recently, this feature has stopped working. I get the following 404 error when I attempt to update the ruleset to 2.2.4:

```
$ ./rules-updater.pl -rhttp://www.modsecurity.org/autoupdate/repository -prepository/ -Smodsecurity-crs
Could not load GnuPG module - cannot verify ruleset signatures
Fetching: modsecurity-crs/modsecurity-crs_2.2.3.zip ...
Failed to retrieve ruleset modsecurity-crs/modsecurity-crs_2.2.3.zip: 404 Not Found
```

We have a cron job which downloads and applies the rules frequently. It's been great up till now. Has anybody found a solution to this? Is anybody aware of other free/open repositories with self-update scripts? I've searched the forums, but no luck so far. Any help is greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for 2.2.3, which isn't there, so no surprise it fails. Sounds like you should report a bug  to them.

Comment: For anybody else interested, I've opened a bug for tracking purposes. It can be found here: https://www.modsecurity.org/tracker/browse/CORERULES-80